# Android pass data to broadcast receiver not working

Tags: android

I want to send multiple sms. I have a while loop that reads from the database and passes the message ID to a broadcast receiver marks the message as sent. If I try to send multiple messages, the broadcast receives only the ID for the first messages even when the message being sent is not the first. You would expect the broadcast receiver to receive the ID for the corresponding sms but that is not the case. How can I fix this?

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String _ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedContract.Entry._ID));
            int triesCount = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedContract.Entry.TRIES_COUNT));
            triesCount += 1;

            Intent smsSentIntent = new Intent(Constants.SMS_SENT_BROADCAST_NAME);
            smsSentIntent.putExtra(FeedContract.Entry._ID, _ID);
            smsSentIntent.putExtra(FeedContract.Entry.TRIES_COUNT, triesCount);

            Intent smsDeliveredIntent = new Intent(Constants.SMS_DELIVERED_BROADCAST_NAME);
            smsDeliveredIntent.putExtra(FeedContract.Entry._ID, _ID);
            smsDeliveredIntent.putExtra(FeedContract.Entry.TRIES_COUNT, triesCount);

            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents = new ArrayList<>();
            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, smsSentIntent, 0);

            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredPendingIntents = new ArrayList<>();
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, smsDeliveredIntent, 0);

            try {
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                ArrayList<String> mSMSMessage = sms.divideMessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedContract.Entry.SMS_BODY)));
                for (int i = 0; i < mSMSMessage.size(); i++) {
                    sentPendingIntents.add(i, sentPI);
                    deliveredPendingIntents.add(i, deliveredPI);
                }

                sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedContract.Entry.RECIPIENTS)), null, mSMSMessage, sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);              

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
```

And on the broadcast receiver I have the following.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String _ID = extras.getString(FeedContract.Entry._ID);   
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sent Message ID " + _ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set data in intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_MEDICINE_KEY, medicineName);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
```

And in onReceive()

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String medName = intent.getStringExtra(ReminderActivity.INTENT_MEDICINE_KEY);

        NotificationManager  notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification, context.getString(R.string.medication_alarm), 
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MedicationActivity.class), 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.notification_message)+" "+medName, 
                contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(R.string.alarm_tag, notification);

        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but your code gets the same if used in a loop